# SendGrid Email delivery status API

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am current using the SendGrid email API with Node.js to send an email using their sample code on GitHub.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

I would like to be able to show the delivery status of this email in my app.
Is this possible using the SendGrid API and if so, how should I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for this, But they have email activity API which you have to subscribe separately.
[email activity](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages)

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "api.sendgrid.com",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/v3/messages?query=status="processed" AND to_email="<<email>>"",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>"
  }
};

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
      });
    });

    req.write("{}");
    req.end();
```

Also, check this for compund query:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api/

Some of email activity :
[image]

Comment: Great, thank! Is it possible to check the delivery status of a specific message using this method? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think. See this https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed/

Comment: @TomCoomer, is it fulfill your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Sendgrid has webhooks, that can update your app with information like delivered or deferred etc. here is a link https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/
and look here too for different responses that sendgrid can send you https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/